# Disable/Hide "View connection settings" option in Available Networks List

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, delphi

Is there a way for disabling or hiding the "View Connection Settings" option in Windows 8.1 and the "Network settings" option in Windows 10?

I work with Delphi XE7 and I'm developing a kiosk application. In Windows 8.1 I use the van.dll for showing the "Available Networks List" and in Windows 10 I use the ms-availablenetworks: command for showing it.

I don't want the users to access the Connection/Network settings option.

[image: Connection/Network settings option]

Comment: I think there are some options via Group Policy, but can't find any specifics atm

Comment: Yeah, but also I don't know if any of them could do the right thing. I searched already for possible parameters for van.dll but nothing and tried to hide settings pages (hide:network-vpn;datausage;network-mobilehotspot...) in Windows registry, but can not reach my goal; when I hide all of them, then when user click on option, appears the Windows Settings Window.

Comment: Hide network icon from taskbar and then use in-app network selection and connection.